# socat LISTEN on existed unix domain socket

Tags: socat

Now I am using socat to forwarding between unix domain socket and tcp socket.

```
sudo socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/usbmuxd,mode=777,reuseaddr,fork TCP:10.16.89.10:10015
```

With this command it require the file `/var/run/usbmuxd` is not exist. Is there any socat option to listen on existed unix domain socket

Answer (score 2):

The unlink-early option to UNIX-LISTEN will remove the file first. That could work for you.

Comment: But I don't want to delete the existing file.

Answer (score 1):

Learning from many I've written so simple :))

**UNIX_SOCKET_DUMP**   bash executable

```
#!/bin/bash
restore(){
    mv $1.original $1
    echo -e "\nSocket $1 \e[33mRESTORED"
}

sock="$1"
trap "restore $sock" EXIT
mv "$sock" "$sock.original"

socat -t100 -v  UNIX-LISTEN:$sock,mode=777,reuseaddr,fork  UNIX-CONNECT:$sock.original
```

create system command `ln -s path/unix_socket_dump /usr/local/bin/xdump`

**ex:**  sniffing postfix smtp socket

```
sock=/var/spool/postfix/private/smtp
xdump $sock
   
# -- second terminal -- push smth in the socket 
echo BlaBlaBla | socat unix:$sock -
```